# Execution trapped inside the button

Tags: java, swing, button, execution

I have a method called inside a button that run almost an infinite loop. I can't access the other buttons while running this method.

How I make to free the interface to access other buttons while running this method?

```
//methods inside the button
this.setCrawlingParameters();
webcrawler = MasterCrawler.getInstance();
webcrawler.resumeCrawling(); //<-- the infinite loop method
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to use a [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

The way Swing works is that it has one main thread, the Event Dispatch Thread(EDT) that manages the UI.  In the Swing documentation, you will see that it is recommended to never to long-running tasks in the EDT, because, since it manages the UI, if you do something computationally heavy your UI will freeze up.  This is exactly what you are doing.

So you need to have your button invoke a SwingWorker so the hard stuff is done in another thread.  Be careful not to modify UI elements from the SwingWorker; all UI code needs to be executed in the EDT.

If you click the link for SwingWorker, you will see this:

> Time-consuming tasks should not be run
> on the Event Dispatch Thread.
> Otherwise the application becomes
> unresponsive. Swing components should
> be accessed on the Event Dispatch
> Thread only

as well as links to examples on how to use a SwingWorker.

Comment: I need to extend the SwingWorker class and implement the methods? I'm confused about the usage.

Comment: @renato, exactly.  The link has a simple example.  If you can't get your swingworker to work, post another question.

Comment: Using Swing Worker now, looks good. Currently I have two process running in background, one that update statistics and another that run download of pages.

Answer (score 3):

Start a new Thread:

```
// In your button:
Runnable runner = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
         setCrawlingParameters(); // I removed the "this", you can replace with a qualified this
         webcrawler = MasterCrawler.getInstance();
         webcrawler.resumeCrawling(); //<-- the infinite loop method
    }
}
new Thread(runner, "A name for your thread").start();
```

Comment: while its true that the main fix is to not do expensive work in the EDT, shouldn't he use a SwingWorker?

Comment: it depends essentially whether there is some UI feedback during this long process. If there's no feedback, then a simple Thread might be enough.

Comment: but one important point is that `setCrawlingParameters()` should not access any UI component, since it is not called from the EDT. Otherwise it should be called outside `run()` (before).

Comment: @jfpoilpret, right i mentioned the dangers of accessing UI elements from anywhere but the EDT.